# Rewriting SharePoint URL in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, url

just a short quick question: Is it possible to rewrite a URL in SharePoint online from contoso.sharepoint.com to product.company.cc with the help of a reverse proxy?

I can not find anything online if that is possible, so this is kind of my last resort.

Kind Regards and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> If your organization has gone through a rebranding, merger, or acquisition and needs to change the domain in your SharePoint and OneDrive URLs, you can do this using PowerShell. For example, if your organization name changed from Contoso to Fabrikam, you can change your SharePoint URLs from `contoso.sharepoint.com` to `fabrikam.sharepoint.com`.

Check related information in detail at this Microsoft official documentation: [Change your SharePoint domain name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name)

You can also add and use custom domains in your Microsoft 365 tenant. Check this Microsoft official documentation: [Add a domain to Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain?view=o365-worldwide)